# "Runtime Error #1004: specified item not found" - A loop through worsheets and objects

Tags: excel, vba

I have 10 sheets with names ranging from "1Store" through "10Store" and, within each of these sheets, 10 persons with 16 pictures each, as in detail:

**Sheet "1Store"** (2 x 8 x 10 pictures in total, all with different names)
Person 1 of the 1st Store:

- 2 pictures named "No1-1-A", "Yes1-1-A" ( reserved to cell "P16")
- 2 pictures named "No1-1-B", "Yes1-1-B" ( reserved to cell "P31")
(...)

- 2 pictures named "No1-1-H", "Yes1-1-H" ( reserved to cell "P115") 

Person 2 of the 1st Store:

- 2 pictures named "No2-1-A", "Yes2-1-A" ( reserved to cell "AE16") 
- 2 pictures named "No2-1-B", "Yes2-1-B" ( reserved to cell "AE31")
(...)

- 2 pictures named "No2-1-H", "Yes2-1-H" ( reserved to cell "AE115")

> and so on... ultil

Person 10 of the 1st Store:

- 2 pictures named "No10-1-A", "Yes10-1-A" ( reserved to cell "FC16") 
- 2 pictures named "No10-1-B", "Yes10-1-B" ( reserved to cell "FC31")
(...)
- 2 pictures named "No10-1-H", "Yes10-1-H" ( reserved to cell "FC115")

> And the sheets go on until sheet "10Store", as below:

**Sheet "10Store"** (2 x 8 x 10 pictures in total, all with different names)

Person 1 of the 10th Store:

- 2 pictures named "No1-10-A", "Yes1-10-A" ( reserved to cell "P16") 
- 2 pictures named "No1-10-B", "Yes1-10-B" ( reserved to cell "P31")
(...)
 
- 2 pictures named "No1-10-H", "Yes1-10-H" ( reserved to cell "P115")

Person 2 of the 10th Store:

- 2 pictures named "No2-10-A", "Yes2-10-A" ( reserved to cell "AE16") 
- 2 pictures named "No2-10-B", "Yes2-10-B" ( reserved to cell "AE31")
(...) 
- 2 pictures named "No2-10-H", "Yes2-10-H" ( reserved to cell "AE115")
 

Person 10 of the 10th Store:

- 2 pictures named "No10-10-A", "Yes10-10-A" ( reserved to cell "FC16") 
- 2 pictures named "No10-10-B", "Yes10-10-B" ( reserved to cell "FC31")
(...)
- 2 pictures named "No10-10-H", "Yes10-10-H" ( reserved to cell "FC115")

> ... as in Person 1 (cell P), Person 2 (cell AE), Person 3 (cell AU),
>   Person 4 (cell BK), Person 5 (cell CA), Person 6 (cell CQ), Person 7
>   (cell DG), Person 8 (cell DW), Person 9 (cell EM), Person 10 (cell FC)*

**[QUESTION]: I am getting "VBA Runtime Error 1004: specified item not found”. All the pictures are there and named. How can I have that script working?**

```
Sub test()
Dim i,j As Integer
i=1 'Store
j=1 'Person
For i = 1 To 10
  For j = 1 to 10

    If Sheets("" & i & "Store").Range("P16").Value = 0 Then

        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-A")).Visible = True
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("Yes" & j & "-" & i & "-A")).Visible = False
    Else
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-A")).Visible = False
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("Yes" & j & "-" & i & "-A")).Visible = True

    End if

    If Sheets("" & i & "Store").Range("P31").Value = 0 Then

        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-B")).Visible = True
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("Yes" & j & "-" & i & "-B")).Visible = False
    Else
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-B")).Visible = False
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("Yes" & j & "-" & i & "-B")).Visible = True

    End if

      (...) 

    If Sheets("" & i & "Store").Range("FC115").Value = 0 Then

        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-H")).Visible = True
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("Yes" & j & "-" & i & "-H")).Visible = False
    Else
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-H")).Visible = False
        Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("Yes" & j & "-" & i & "-H")).Visible = True

    End if

      (...) Above, it correlates all 10 Persons with all 10 stores (from P16-A,..., FC115-H) 

       Next j
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: @Comintern Hi! Second line --> Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-A")).Visible = True

Comment: What is the value of i and j when it crashes?

Comment: I do not know how to discover these values, since the debug marker pinpoints only the error line. How to verify them? Anyway, I added a test file as an attachment just in the comment down below. Please check

Comment: Just hover your cursor over the variables "i" and "j" and it should show the values.  Or, in the immediate window, enter the commands `?i` and `?j`.  Or, add the line `MsgBox "i=" & i & ", j=" & j` to your code immediately after your `For j = 1 To 10` line and remember which was the last value it displayed before the crash.  (If your code is at fault, I would expect it to crash when i and j are both 1.  If your pictures are at fault, the values **may** be higher.)

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you for the mouse over tips. Interesting information! I found out, amidst all those pictures in my file, three ones with wrong names/references. The script is working now without the “error #1004” but it is not working as it was conceived in my mind : ). There are some marked cells in my worksheets that retain some values (0 or 1) and which trigger the visibility of pictures or just plain hide them from view. The new problem begins when the first cell in this list is "0", so all the ones in the same sheet will be visible too. (continues...)

Comment: @YowE3K Even though there are other cells having the value of "1", they should, therefore, force pictures to be invisible. I have improved a lot the coding presented in the beginning to just a few 20 or less lines. As I cannot advance further in the new programming error, I had to get round this issue by writing around 700+ lines of code. It is not a clean and smart code, but the actions I envisaged are now working. (continues ...)

Comment: @YowE3K Anyway, I would like to state that I placed an abridged version of the problem I faced in an Excel file linked to my Google drive (cloud), as suggested by another user, since this is a quite standard procedure in other forums. By no means it contains malicious code that can hijack information or damage any computer whatsoever in this community. But I respect your wish to not visit external links.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834903.aspx): "Can be an integer that specifies the index number of the shape, a string that specifies the name of the shape, or an array that contains either integers or strings."  The `Array` call isn't doing anything unless you have shapes named "Yes", "No", 1, 2, etc.  You just need to do simple concats:

```
Sheets(i & "Store").Shapes.Range("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-A").Visible = True
```

Comment: I have images. Did what you have suggested and no changes so far. Same error.

Comment: I have removed the `For j = 1 to 10` and simplified for testing as in: `Sheets(i & "Store").Shapes.Range("N1-" & i).Visible = True`. It is OK! But when I add the following:`Sheets(i & "Store").Shapes.Range("N1-" & i & "-1B").Visible = True`, the same error again.

Comment: @LuizVaughan - in your last comment you said that `Sheets(i & "Store").Shapes.Range("N1-" & i).Visible = True` works.  That statement has no reference to the "-A" etc at the end of the name, and uses "N" instead of "No".  Are they just typos in your comment (hopefully) or is that a clue to the problem.

Comment: @YowE3K Just typos regarding "N1","1B" as it should have been respectively "No-","-B" instead, sorry. Anyway, those are just fragments of names that are under quotation marks and names can be anything we wish. It might be something wrong with the concatenate `&` operator that I just don't know yet how to solve. Could you please make a quick simulation on your machine by placing random photos in Excel sheets and by naming them as presented above?

Comment: I added a picture to a worksheet, used the command `sheets("1Store").shapes(1).name ="No1-1-A"` to set its name (I don't use pictures and Shapes, so I wasn't sure whether there was an easier way to do that), and then successfully ran your code through the `Sheets("" & i & "Store").Shapes.Range(Array("No"  & j & "-" & i & "-A")).Visible = True` line of your code

Comment: This is a picture simulation that I want to make it work. I cannot correct the errors. I have tried everything I could. In fact, the real Excel file has more than 1600 pictures. This is just a rehearsal to understand the whole mechanism. See attached file. It is a good challenge for the Gurus out there. Please, help... [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_TpNtEoBKu2Mlo3ZWJXaGl1LXM/view?usp=sharing)